# Validad login con php 5.6 y SQL Server 2014

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Tengo un login y funciona si ingreso datos correctos pero si ingreso incorrectos me lleva a otra web y muestra un alert y se queda ahí, lo que quiero es que no me lleve a ninguna web mas bien solo muestre un alert de que los campos son nulos o incorrectos y solo envié los datos ingresados si son  true, es decir, hacer match con los campos de mi base de datos, dejo el `php`.

```
<?php
    require('conexion.php');
    $username = $_POST['txt1'];
    $password  = $_POST['txt2'];

    if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
        echo "<script>alert('Llena todos los campos!');</script>";
        die();
    }else{
        $tsql = "SELECT * FROM CatUsuarios WHERE U_UsdName='$username' AND U_Password='$password'";
    }
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
    while($Row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
        if($stmt == true){
            $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
            header('Location: index.php');
            die();
        }else{
             echo "<script>alert('Datos incorrectos!');</script>";
            die();
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que deberías usar es ajax para no refrescar tu pagina

ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'login.php',
   //dataType: 'html',//el tipo de dato que regresara en la repuesta tambien puede ser json
   data: {"user":user,"password":password},
   success: function(response)
   {
       if(response)
         alert(response);
   },
   error:function(error){
      alert("error occured:"); //===Show Error Message====
   }
```

});

y en tu php login.php

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password  = $_POST['password'];
$msg="";
if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
    $msg='Llena todos los campos!';

}
else{
    $tsql = "SELECT * FROM CatUsuarios WHERE U_UsdName='$username' AND U_Password='$password'";
}
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if($stmt){
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
    $msg="";
}
else
   $msg='Datos incorrectos!';
echo $msg;
//echo json_encode(array('success' => 1:'msg'=>$msg));//Tambien lo puedes regresar como json
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu orientacion, manos a la obra

Comment: el ajax lo pongo en el login.php verdad

Comment: el codigo que mostre se llama log.php, el login esta el front del login

Comment: el ajax debe estar en tu front donde tienes tu vista o en un script.js(recomendable) y tu login .php en tu back